# How to find possible Combination Pair and Match against different Pairs from the given Player list using Java Stream API

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm try to creating the possible combination of pair in the given players list, also Want to find the possible match among those different pairs.

- Created a Pojo Class for a Pair - with fields as Player 1 and Player 2.
- Iterated list with possible different pair (like p1,p2 & p3,p4 & p2,p3 etc.. )
- Then find possible different pairs against in a match ( How many matches are possible).

---

```
public class CombinationCreator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> playerList = Arrays.asList("PlayerA","PlayerB","PlayerC","PlayerD","PlayerE","PlayerF");
        List<PlayPair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

        playerList.forEach(p -> {
            playerList.stream().filter(p2 -> !p.equals(p2)).forEach(p2 -> pairs.add(new PlayPair(p, p2)));
        });

        //Printing all possbile pair ( with duplicate)
        pairs.forEach(c-> System.out.println(c));           
    }
}
```

Pair Class POJO:

```
public class PlayPair {

    private String player1;
    private String player2;
    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PlayPair [player1=" + player1 + ", player2=" + player2 + "]";
    }

    public PlayPair(String player1, String player2) {
        super();
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        PlayPair other = (PlayPair) obj;
        if (player1 == null) {
            if (other.player1 != null)
                return false;
        } else if (player2 == null) {
            if (other.player2 != null)
                return false;
        }

        if (!((player1.equals(other.player1) && player2.equals(other.player2))
                || (player1.equals(other.player2) && player2.equals(other.player1))))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Since I'm very new to Java Stream API and lambda, I'm a bit struggling to find the combination. In Classic Java7, the code seems very clumsy not an effective way. Is there an easiest and simple coding can resolve my issues?

Comment: Just to clarify, what would be the expected output for current input and what would be the expected output if the input was `Arrays.asList("PlayerA","PlayerB","PlayerC","PlayerD","PlayerE","PlayerF", "PlayerC")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the current code, you can use `flatMap` while using the `stream` of the list of players to `map` them to `PlayPair` as:

```
Set<PlayPair> pairs = playerList.stream()
        .flatMap(player1 -> playerList.stream()
                .filter(player2 -> !player1.equals(player2))
                .map(player2 -> new PlayPair(player1, player2)))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)); // for unique ordered pairs
```

Comment: Do note that, the `equals` comparison and the corresponding result would rely on the overridden implementation as shared by you.

Comment: But i can see the dulicate Pair in the results - in both case ( removing & adding my implementation of equal )

Comment: @YuvarajAK That's quite possible if you mean the pair `A,F` and `F,A` are duplicates. Given the default `equals` implementation would not treat them equal and your overridden implementation seems to be functionally incorrect as well. By the way, are you saying the current implementation as shared in the question results in a different result?

Comment: yes , im considering the pairs -  A,F and F,A are duplicates. Implemenented the equal methods to avoid the match against the same pairs ( when try avoid the match A,F with F,A)